# Converting ArrayBuffer to int in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I am trying to convert an ArrayBuffer to an int using JavaScript. My app uses WebSocket and on the Sender side I have an integer between 0 and 4. I convert this ArraySegment in C#. I send this via web sockets to my JavaScript client which receives it as an ArrayBuffer.

The ArrayBuffer now holds the value of 0 or 1 or 2 or 3. How can I 'read' that value?

Comment: Why not use DataView? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView

Comment: @stdob This looks cool. I need to test 1st. thanks

Comment: @stdob-- Quick question is this DataView compatible with all modern browsers?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView#Browser_compatibility

Comment: {sorry feel stupid now}

Comment: Be carefull there is an endianness here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView):

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
var dv = new DataView(buffer, 0);

dv.setInt16(1, 42);
dv.getInt16(1); //42
```

Comment: Is this base zero or starts from 1 as you have in your example?

Comment: I use this:  var dv = new DataView(e.Data); var index = dv.getInt16(1); but all I get is zero?  I know (for testing I am passing a '3')?

Comment: In DataView constructor offset relatively to ArrayBuffer, in `setInt16` or `getInt16` relatively to DataView.

Comment: yes, that is what I tried.  So, my ArrayBuffer is say 1000 length in bytes. I just want to read the very 1st byte as an integer?  ( have said in my code myArray[0]=(byte)3 you see

Comment: Ok, let try `getInt8(0)` instead `getInt16(0)`?

Comment: Will try, but need to reboot pc 1st :)

Comment: @stdob-- The second param to setInt16, why are you passing 42? I have been looking at the docs and cannot figure out what is supposed to be passed there

Comment: @YourGoodFriend This is just an example. It can be either 42, or another number - for example 32767 )) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setInt16

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = new Uint8Array(buf)[0];
```

Then `i` is what you need. If you need `subarray()`:

```
ArrayBuffer.prototype.subarray = function (a, b) {
    var u = new Uint8Array(this);
    return new Uint8Array(u.subarray(a, b)).buffer;;
};
```

and

```
var i = new Uint8Array(buf.subarray(0,1))[0];
```